# Automatically converse value type to String in Magento when creating grid

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

This Magento version is 1.9.

I would like to create a grid related to product inventory. The grid consists of `Product_Id`, `Product_name`, `Price`, `Final_Price`, `Qty`, `Unused_Qty`, `Actual_Qty`.

If product does not belong to Group deals, `Unused_Qty` is set null or 0. `Actual_Qty` is set same as `Qty`.

If product belongs to Group deals, both value are set the following:

**[Unused_Qty]**

```
select g.product_id,
    ifnull(gc.unused_cnt, 0) as unused_qty
from groupdeals g
left join ( 
    SELECT product_id,
           count(product_id) as unused_cnT
    FROM groupdeals_coupons
    where redeem = "not_used"
    group by product_id
) gc on g.product_id = gc.product_id
```

**[Actual_Qty]

Qty + Unused_Qty**

However, type of four items, which are `Final_Price`, `Qty`, `Unused_Qty`, `Actual_Qty`, were conversed to String, not number even if I tried various ways, such as combination of joinleft and `Zend_Db_Expr`, `Varien_Data_Collection`.

Ex. not working

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    $collection
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')     
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')  
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->getSelect()

    ->join(array('csi' => 'cataloginventory_stock_item'),
        'e.entity_id = csi.product_id',
        array('csi.qty' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(cast(csi.qty AS UNSIGNED))'))
    )
    ->joinleft(
        array('gc' => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                            '(select g.product_id, ' .
                                        'ifnull(gc.unused_cnt, 0) as unused_qty ' .
                            'from groupdeals g ' .
                            'left join ( ' . 
                                'SELECT product_id, ' .
                                        'count(product_id) as unused_cnt ' .
                                'FROM groupdeals_coupons ' .
                                'where redeem = "not_used" ' .
                                'group by product_id ' .
                            ') gc on g.product_id = gc.product_id)')),
        'e.entity_id = gc.product_id',
        array('gc.unused_qty',
                'actual_qty' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(ifnull(truncate(csi.qty + gc.unused_qty, 0), ' .
                                                            'truncate(csi.qty, 0)))'))
    );
```

So, it occured error when filtering or sorting. Do you happen to know why value type was automatically changed from number to String?

Incidentally, it worked if using joinField.

```
$collection
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')     
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')  
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->joinField('qty',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    );
```

Comment: what is the DB types for these fields?  in PHP it's unnecessary to use the `.` at the end of a line.  PHP understands multi-line strings just fine.

Comment: Thank for your response. As far as I know, these fields type are almost decimal and MySQL is used , but I could not check the DB version unless tomorrow comes. Then, I had no idea dot at the end of a line is not necessary. Thank you for your advice. I try it.

Comment: Yea the extra `.` just makes it harder to read.  You could also use a HEREDOC  ( NEWDOC ) for it, which is what I do for big strings, but thats a bit off the topic.  Generally the types in the database will dictate what the return values are typed as ( thats just mysql, not specifically Magneto )

Comment: I am afraid It does not make sense the description related to return values. For example, I checked the type of Qty, which is contained in coding, is decimal(12, 4). So, I think the extracted value type is double. Is my thinking correct?